# Naming convention for a class which manages File serialization and deserialization

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

Is there a naming convention for a class which manages serialization and de-serialization of data? An example of such class would be the MFC CDocument class which acts as the bridge between File data and App data. As in, what are these types of classes typically called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in the BCL (.NET Base Class Library), these are called Serializers or Formatters.

Examples include the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx), [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) and [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

All of these classes manage both serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: Even if this class is responsible for de-serializing file data to object data?

Comment: @user965369 - All of those classes manage both. If you have separate types that handle each, name them accordingly.

Comment: @user965369 - Which kind of tells you that there is no general convention between OOP languages ;)